# Symfony 4: How to authenticating users?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm starting to learn Symfony. I would like to create an API accessible with authentication.
I followed the symfony documentation for creating an API skeleton (composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project) then I followed the security section (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html).
I arrived to the part 3a "Authentication & Firewalls". I updated the config/packages/security.yaml file then I installed the profiler.

This is my security.yaml file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: argon2i
            cost: 12

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

When I go to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" I have the profiler bar but I'm not authenticated as anonymous, I'm not authenticated at all. So did I forget to do/configure something?
This is what I see in the profiler bar: 
[image: my result]

Comment: Authentication means “login”. Did you actually log in?

Comment: In the documentation it is written "Don't be fooled by the "Yes" next to Authenticated. The firewall verified that it does not know your identity, and so, you are anonymous" plus "A firewall is your authentication system". Does it means I have to be connected to the application? It is not completely clear for me.
I was thinking that the firewall would force the user to be logged in before accessing the application or the api.

Comment: You firewall is not configured to handle authentication! you can try with http_basic and configure access_control

Comment: unless `access_control` is activated, access is not controlled (duh).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: Finally, I added api-platform to my project so it handles Api natively.
Thanks for your help.